# How to cancel an ADO online reservation?

Tags: buses, mexico

I reserved a bus ticket from Oaxaca to CDMX using the ADO app. I selected "pay at box office" as the payment option.

However, I quickly realized that I made the reservation for the wrong day. Since I haven't given them my credit card info yet, I'm wondering if I have to cancel my reservation, or can I just not show up, and they will give my seat to someone else without penalizing me in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I called the box office and they canceled my reservation for free.

Later, I found out that I could simply not show up, and the reservation would be automatically cancelled without any penalty. But I think it's best to call them to cancel your reservation so that another person would be able reserve your seat.